# SharePoint 2013 Calendar: Delete single item from recurrence event using Designer Workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I am able to delete single item from Calendar using "*Delete Item in {this list}*" action in Designer Workflow.

However, I am not able to delete single instance of Recurrence Event.

Does anyone know, if it's possible to delete single item of Recurrence Event from SharePoint 2013 Calendar, using Designer Workflow?